# Checking for duplicates in Database and running a function

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I need to check if an ip_adress is already in my database if it is i need to update row 'visit' and add 1. if it doesnt exit then add the ip_adress to my database in row 'ip_adress' here is my code:

```
<?php include'connect.php';
//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip = ip2long($ip);


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ip_adress FROM ip_visits");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $ip_adress = $row['ip_adress'];
  if($ip_adress === $ip){
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ip_visits SET ip_adress = ip_adress + 1");
  }else{
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ip_visits (ip_adress) VALUES ('$ip')");
  }
```

}

```
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UNIQUE` key on `ip_adress` and then

```
INSERT INTO ip_visits (ip_adress)
  VALUES ('$ip')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE visits=visits+1
```

Except use a parametrized query.

Comment: what is a parametrized query?

Comment: It's something that's explained in a better tutorial than your current one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you are looking for it is exactly what @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has shown you.

It goes like this:

1) Tell MySql to insert into the desired table.

2) Explain to it that you'd to rather prefer it to UPDATE in case it finds a duplicate key.

CODE:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Which will be more or less equal to saying:

```
UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

The advantage of doing the `INSERT` part is that the `UPDATE` alone will do nothing if it finds nothing to be updated.

So, the `INSERT,UPDATE` combination is like killing 2 Birds with one stone.

You can read more here:

## http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Just a side note, makes sure your table has at least a primary key and auto_increment field